# Download file from Azure Blob

Tags: asp.net, azure, model-view-controller, azure-storage

I am trying to download a file from my Azure blob server, for some reason it gives me the error `The argument types 'Edm.Int32' and 'Edm.String' are incompatible for this operation. Near WHERE predicate, line 1, column 84.`

the fileName is correct and gives the name for the file uploaded, however, I am not sure how to set the OpenWrite to download the file. If i've understood this correctly, the OpenWrite sets where the file is to be downloaded. However I just need to be able to click the "Download" button starting this and have the file start to download wherever the user chooses to do so by default, usually "Downloads"

```
public EmptyResult Download(string id)
        {
            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(
            CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("filestorageideagen_AzureStorageConnectionString"));

            CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

            CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("documentuploader");

            DocumentUps documentUps = db.DocumentUps.Find(id);

            string fileName = id.ToString() + documentUps.RevisionId.ToString() + documentUps.Attachment.ToString();

            CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(fileName);


            using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenWrite(????))
            {
                blob.DownloadToStream(fileStream);
            }


            return new EmptyResult();
        }
```

Comment: Sounds more like your problem is with the (document) database query and not with Azure Storage.

Comment: @haim770 I never even thought of that but thinking logically, you may be right, Ill take a look into it now

Comment: One more thing: `blob.DownloadToStream(fileStream);` will actually download the file on your web server and not on the client machine.

Comment: @GauravMantri How would I change it to download to the client machine?

Comment: @CaptainCanada ^-- let's not ask additional questions in comments - StackOverflow doesn't support "discussions." Please ask a separate question for that.

Comment: @CaptainCanada  its part of his question and a good one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, as haim770 said, the error seems not be caused by Azure storage code, please debug the code to find the code snippet that causes the error.

> How would I change it to download to the client machine?

If you’d like to enable clients to download Azure Blob storage via your Web API, please refer to the following code to implement your controller action.

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Get()
{
    try
    {
        var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("{connection string}");
        var blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

        var Blob = await blobClient.GetBlobReferenceFromServerAsync(new Uri("https://{storageaccount}.blob.core.windows.net/{mycontainer}/{blobname.txt}"));
        var isExist = await Blob.ExistsAsync();

        if (!isExist) { 
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "file not found");
        }

        HttpResponseMessage message = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        Stream blobStream = await Blob.OpenReadAsync();

        message.Content = new StreamContent(blobStream);
        message.Content.Headers.ContentLength = Blob.Properties.Length;
        message.Content.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue(Blob.Properties.ContentType);
        message.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
        {
            FileName = "{blobname.txt}",
            Size = Blob.Properties.Length
        };

        return message;

}    
catch (Exception ex)

    {

        return new HttpResponseMessage

        {
            StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError,
            Content = new StringContent(ex.Message)
        };

    }

}
```

Comment: how to make sure that the stream closes if the user aborts the download? How is that implicitly handled with the given code?